# Casting to superclass in php

Tags: php, datetime

I am looking for a way to cast a class to its parent. The situation:

In an effort to reduce juggling with DateTime objects, I extended the DateTime class to include a `__toString` method.

```
class myDateTime extends DateTime{
public $formatstring = null;

public function format($format = null) {
    if(null === $format){
        $format = $this->formatstring;
    }
    if(null === $format){
        $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
    }

    return parent::format($format);
}

public function __toString(){
    return $this->format();
}

}
```

While this works beautifully, I later found it is breaking `DateTime::diff`, which I am assuming is checking that the incoming `object` is `DateTime`.

```
public function TotalTime(){
    $start = $this->getStart();
    $end   = $this->getEnd();
    $diff  = $end->diff($start);

    $minutes = 
        ($diff->days*1440) +
        ($diff->h * 60) +
        ($diff->i *  1) +
        ($diff->s / 60);

    echo("<pre>Start:$start\nEnd:$end\nMin:$minutes\n</pre>");
    var_dump($diff);

    return $minutes;
}
```

The resulting DateInterval always has every value zeroed.

Any suggestions on the most efficient way to do a typecast of an inherited class? PHP 5.4

*EDIT:*
This appears to be environment dependant. Currently, this only seems to occur on Windows/PHP.

```
PHP 5.4.10 (cli) (built: Dec 19 2012 20:33:35)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: It's not possible to cast objects in php

Comment: "I later found it is breaking" --- in what particular way?

Comment: add static `diff` method with one parameter to your class and call that: `myDateTime::diff`, convert your data in class to `DateTime` object and call `DateTime::diff` or implement your code.

Comment: @zerkms: editted to give example of usage

Comment: @mkjasinski: sorry, didn't even see your response before I submitted my answer... basically did what you said.

Comment: "which I am assuming is checking that the incoming `object` is `DateTime`", but any object of class `myDateTime` **IS** also an instance of `DateTime`, so this is really strange.

Comment: It appears that `diff` is explicitly looking for "DateTime" rather than instanceof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you just need to ask the question to answer it.

So since we can't cast, we will have to create a new object. We just need to make sure to check the inheritance better than the `DateTime` object (if you are fixing something, fix it better than the original problem). This method overrides the parent method:

```
public function diff($object,$absolute=false){
    if($object instanceof DateTime){
        $object = new DateTime($object);
    }
    return parent::diff($object,$absolute);
}
```

This checks the inheritance tree to see if anything in the past ever inheritted from DateTime, this will allow it to continue working if someone else were to inherit from `myDateTime`.

Comment: `if(in_array('DateTime',class_parents($object))){` -> `instanceof` ?

Comment: @zerkms: yes, edit to reflect suggestion. (I even looked for something that would do that :)

Comment: You don't need this function to make it work, just see this demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/izOh5p

Comment: Not required on my Mac machine, is required on my Win machine. Interesting.